# Writing to a directory within app's documents directory error

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I must be missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to find the answer.  Basically, I used to have code that wrote a file to the app's documents directory.  That code looks like

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectory;
}
```

// The actual writing code in another method

```
NSString *manifestPath = @"manifest.txt";
[manifestData writeToFile:manifestPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

So this works fine.  Now I want to create a new folder within the documents directory and write to that folder.  So to create my new folder I do:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL isDir;
NSString *directoryPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDir"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath isDirectory:&isDir]) {
    if (!isDir) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
}
```

That part works fine.

The part that doesn't work, is when I want to create my new manifestPath to go to this directory and write to that directory.  I've tried

```
NSString *manifestPath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manifest.txt"]];
```

or

```
NSString *manifestPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/manifest.txt", directoryPath];
```

Am I missing something with the way paths, or directories work?  I keep getting Cocoa error 4.  When I print out the path, my path looks correct too.  (iOS simulator directory/testDir/manifest.txt)

Am I missing something here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you keep appending the documents directory path to itself. In your example `directoryPath` already has the documents directory path in it. Just do `[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manifest.txt"]`.